# Disable Quick edit with CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

How can I disable `"Quick edit"` on lists with CSOM?

Comment: Does it have to be done with CSOM? It would be pretty easy to do it via UI: http://mroffice365.com/2013/06/how-to-disable-quick-edit-in-sharepoint-2013-lists/

Comment: Sites and lists are provisioned automatically, so I was using CSOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't, this property is not exposed through csom as of the latest version. (The one released in 12-2015)

The closest thing you can do, is hide the button with javascript